# Not sure how to update this chart with updated array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wrote down a function in my code that updates the data array with user input. Data array is used to construct the bar graph in my code. Currently, my data array in the chart is getting updated upon user input, but not my chart.
[image]
How would I update this chart along with user input. Below is the code so far-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform,StyleSheet,Text,View,SafeAreaView,TextInput,Button,Picker,Alert} from 'react-native';
import Chart from 'react-native-chartjs';

const datas = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datas: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 10],
}

const chartConfiguration = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio : false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
};

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.state = {
      filterLimit: 100,
      lessThanOrGreaterThan: 'lessThan',
      chartConfiguration : chartConfiguration,
      key: Date.now()
    };
}
componentWillMount() {
  this.datas = {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datas: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 10],
  }
}
applyFilter = () => {
  const { filterLimit: value, lessThanOrGreaterThan } = this.state;
  const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === "lessThan";

  // update instance variable
  this.datas.datas = this.datas.datas.map(v => {
    if (isLessThan ? v <= value : v >= value) return v;
    return 0;
  });
  console.log(this.datas.datas)
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    chartConfiguration: {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [this.datas.datas],
          backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1 // <-- copy instance variable for new array reference
        }],
      },
      options: {
      maintainAspectRatio : false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
    },
    key: Date.now(),
  }));
}
  render() {
    return (
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.chartContainer}>
      <View style = {{ flex : 1 }}>
          <Chart chartConfiguration = {
            this.state.chartConfiguration
          }
       defaultFontSize={20}/>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          numeric
          placeholder="Filter Limit"
          value={this.state.filterLimit}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ filterLimit: text })}
        />
        <Button
        onPress={()=>Alert.alert(this.state.filterLimit)}
        title="Filter Limit"
        color="#841584"
      />
      </View>
    <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.lessThanOrGreaterThan}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
          onValueChange={this.handlelessThanOrGreaterThan}
        >
          <Picker.Item label ="Less Than" value="lessThan" />
          <Picker.Item label="Greater Than" value="greaterThan" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
       <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.applyFilter()}
          title = "Apply Filter"
          color="#841584"
      />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

The output I am getting with the above code is below-
[image]
chartConfiguration is a required variable to go with the Chart component. The chart won't re-render, even though the chartConfiguration data array changes within the applyFilter function.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You've a whole mess of object mutations going on. You mutate `this.datas.datas` while iterating over it. You mutate the outer `chartConfiguration` object. `componentWillMount` is practically a deprecated lifecycle method.

But you ***never*** update your `chartConfiguration` state that is passed to `Chart` component. `Chart` always receives the same object reference.

## Solution

Update state that is passed to `Chart` component. Use a functional state update to update from and shallow copy the previous state into new object/array references for the properties that are being updated. I don't see where you bind `this` to `applyFilter` in the constructor, so do that or convert to arrow function.

```
applyFilter = () => {
  const { filterLimit: value, lessThanOrGreaterThan } = this.state;
  const isLessThan = lessThanOrGreaterThan === "lessThan";

  // update instance variable
  this.data.datas = this.datas.datas.map(v => {
    if (isLessThan ? v <= value : v >= value) return v;
    return 0;
  });

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    chartConfiguration: {
      ...prevState.chartConfiguration,
      data: {
        ...prevState.chartConfiguration.data,
        datasets: [{
          ...prevState.chartConfiguration.datasets[0],
          data: [...this.datas.datas], // <-- copy instance variable for new array reference
        }],
      },
    },
    key: Date.now(),
  }));
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code as per your instructions. See updated code in question body. Now when I try to 'Apply Filter', it doesn't return anything. But the array is still updating.

Comment: @tallpotato If it is possible do you think you could create an [Expo Snack](https://expo.io/) with your code in it so we can live debug it?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@anushkas/6daf8a it's staging here with another library